# How can I tell DateTime in C# to set the date to a certain language?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
private DateTime mDate = DateTime.Now;
mDate.ToLongDateString();
```

My location is Germany so it displays for example Samstag as Saturday.

Comment: DateTime does not “have a language”. The localization is applied when *turning the date time into a string*. See the CultureInfo that can be specified.

Comment: oh ok thanks i will try that

Comment: `string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));` here we want complete name of the week day - `"dddd"` in German (`de-DE` stands for deutsch Deutschland)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the current culture before calling `ToLongDateString` as shown in the help for that call at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolongdatestring?view=net-6.0

Or, you can pass an appropriate format string to `ToString` and provide format information as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

For example if you wanted a long date string in French (from France), you could:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("D", culture);
```

Result: `"samedi 18 décembre 2021"`